# How to Pass Additional Parameters When Calling and Event VB.net

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

```
Public Event DocumentCompleted As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler

Dim arg() As Object = {homeTeam, guestTeam}
        AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, New 
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DoStuff)

Private Sub DoStuff(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

How can I pass the homeTeam and guestTeam when firing the DocumentCompleted event.
I want to ge the above to values to inside the Dostuff method.

Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to call DocumentCompleted event manually?

Comment: Nope. I want to pass some additional parameters to the DoStuff method when DocumentCompleted event fires. I just execute browser.Navigate(uri) and then the DoStuff call should work after browser complete loading.

Comment: but DoStuff() is your event handler and will be called automatically at DocumentCompleted event. Where should homeTeam and guestTeam come from?

Comment: Dim arg() As Object = {homeTeam, guestTeam}
        AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, New 
WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DoStuff) 

Above code is in the same method and homTeam and guestTeam are passed to that method and they are known variables when event fires

Comment: if they are known, I assume they are global, so why don't use use them directly in DoStuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have this hanging in the middle of nowhere:

```
Dim arg() As Object = {homeTeam, guestTeam}
AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted,
           New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf DoStuff)
```

`AddHandler` probably needs to be in some `Initialize` method, which could be inside `Sub New`, after `InitializeComponent`, or inside `Form_Load`, or as soon as you expect it to be triggered (after a specific event). Notice here that you are using a default event of a native .NET component, with a default event type. In this case you cannot directly consume anything other than what it already provides, when triggered. See [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx).

You can, however, override all relevant classes and have your own MyWebBrowser control and your own event, with would contain additional properties. See below example:

```
Public Class Form1
  Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim browser As New MyWebBrowser
    AddHandler browser.MyDocumentCompleted, AddressOf DoStuff
  End Sub

  Private Sub DoStuff(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MyWebBrowserDocumentCompletedArgs)
    Dim guestTeam As String = e.GuestTeam 'guest team
    Dim homeTeam As String = e.HomeTeam 'and home team are both accessible
    'so you can do some processing on them
  End Sub

  Public Class MyWebBrowserDocumentCompletedArgs : Inherits WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs
    Dim _homeTeam As String
    Dim _guestTeam As String
    Public ReadOnly Property HomeTeam
      Get
        Return _homeTeam
      End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property GuestTeam
      Get
        Return _guestTeam
      End Get
    End Property

    Sub New(url As Uri, homeTeam As String, guestTeam As String)
      MyBase.New(url)
      _homeTeam = homeTeam
      _guestTeam = guestTeam
    End Sub
  End Class

  Public Class MyWebBrowser : Inherits WebBrowser
    Public Delegate Sub MyWebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(e As MyWebBrowserDocumentCompletedArgs)
    Public Event MyDocumentCompleted As MyWebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDocumentCompleted(e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
      MyBase.OnDocumentCompleted(e)
      'homeTeam and guestTeam need to be extracted from the current instance of MyWebBrowser, and passed further
      RaiseEvent MyDocumentCompleted(New MyWebBrowserDocumentCompletedArgs(e.Url, "homeTeam", "guestTeam"))
    End Sub
  End Class
End Class
```

If your project is relatively small, you can indeed have those as global variables, as @Vlad suggested in the comments.